# How can I print SQL query result log with log4j?

Tags: sql, spring, jdbc, log4j, mybatis

I'm using Spring 3.1.1, MyBatis 3.1.1, MySQL 5.0.67. My Spring configuration is below:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">    
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="14400000"/>               
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="false"/>       
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis/myBatisConfig.xml"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionTemplate" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="sqlSessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

And log4.properties is below:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.mybatis=DEBUG

log4j.logger.java.sql=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.Connection=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.Statement=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet=DEBUG
```

With these configuration, I can see SQL query statement which is executed and parameters to that query but I can't see query result log. My log is like this:

```
[org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] - Creating a new SqlSession
[org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] - SqlSession             [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@4ccdd1f] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
[org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
[org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction] - JDBC Connection     [ProxyConnection[PooledConnection[com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@3cfde82]]] will not be managed by Spring
[java.sql.Connection] - ooo Using Connection     [ProxyConnection[PooledConnection[com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@3cfde82]]]
[java.sql.Connection] - ==>  Preparing: SELECT col FROM table WHERE col1=? AND col2=? 
[java.sql.PreparedStatement] - ==> Parameters: 93(Integer), 4(Integer)
[org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] - Closing non transactional SqlSession     [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@4ccdd1f]
[org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

Is there any way to print log including query result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways:

- log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet=TRACE

Or use the namespaces to set logging. This is the only logging method in mybatis 3.2

http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/logging.html

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is:

log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils=TRACE

This prints entries like these:

```
...
TRACE SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [12345], value class [java.math.BigDecimal], SQL type 3
TRACE SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 2, parameter value [ADDRESS], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type 12
TRACE SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 3, parameter value [20130916], value class [java.math.BigDecimal], SQL type 3
...
```

In my case I am using running a query inside a JdbcBatchItemWriter in a Spring Batch application, which uses named params so it may not be a general solution.